# Two dimensional least squares fitting

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have a two dimensional data set, of some fixed dimensions (`xLen` and `yLen`), which contains a sine curve.

I've already determined the frequency of the sine curve, and I've generated my own sine data with the frequency using

```
SineData = math.sin((2*math.pi*freqX)/xLen + (2*math.pi*freqY)/yLen)
```

where `freqX` and `freqY` and the oscillation frequencies in the X and Y directions for the curve.

But now I'd like to do a linear least squares fit (or something similar), so that I can fit the right amplitude. As far as I know, a linear least squares is the right way to go, but if there's another way that's fine as well.

The `leastsq` function is SciPy doesn't do a multidimensional fit. Is there a python implementation for a 2/multidimensional least square fitting algorithm

**Edit:** I found the 2 dimensional frequency of the sine wave from a 2D FFT. The data contains a 2D sine + noise, so I only picked the largest peak of the 2D FFT and took an inverse of that. Now I have a sine curve, but with an amplitude that's off. Is there a way to do a 2 dimensional least squares (or similar), and fit the amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider a 2D Finite/Discrete Fourier Transform (FFT/DFT) if your data is well served by using trig functions.

NumPy has an [DFT](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) solution built in.

There are lots of places to help you get started; Google found [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/724/low-pass-filter-and-fft-for-beginners-with-python).

Start with your original data.  The transform will tell you if your frequency solution is correct and if there are other frequencies that are also significant.

Comment: A 2D FFT was how I figured out the right frequencies... but the amplitude is off. I was trying to figure out how to get the right amplitude as well, the NumPy scaling doesn't give me the right one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say the amplitude is off.  An FFT will transform you 2D spatial data into amplitude/frequency pairs.  You don't get one amplitude; you get one associated with each frequency.  You might be saying that you've implicitly used a low-pass filter by selecting just one frequency, so the calculated amplitude doesn't match.  I'd recommend being more formal about it by transforming, applying the filter, and then transforming back to see what you get.  That's the function that you should compare to your data.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I meant. I did an FFT of the original signal, and took the frequency corresponding to the largest peak as the frequency of the 2D signal. I then set all the other points (except the ones corresponding to the largest peak) to zero, and took an IFFT. The amplitude is still off, so I'm trying to find a way to fit the amplitude to the original signal.

Comment: There should be two frequencies - one for x and another for y.  Physics will tell you that the fundamentals for both are 2*pi/Lx and 2*pi/Ly, respectively.  I don't know what your boundary conditions are, but if it's x = y = 0 on the boundaries you'll have two sine waves.

Comment: Okay, I think I've been confusing while trying to explain things. The frequency is fine... I've got the right 2 dimensional frequency, one for X and the other for Y, as well as the dimensions in each direction. So the wave per se isn't the problem. It's just that the amplitude of the IFFT'd wave (which is my sine wave, from which I find the frequencies in each direction) is much smaller than the initial curve. I just want to use some fitting algorithm to fit for the amplitude, since the frequencies themselves are fine.

Answer (score 0):

In least squares fitting , one minimizes a residual function, perhaps chisquare.  Since this involves summing estimates corresponding to the difference squared at each of the points of model minus data, the number of dimensions is "forgotten" in making the residual.  Thus all the values in the 2D difference function array can be copied to a 1D array as the result of the residual function supplied to, for example, `leastsq`.  An example for complex to real rather than 2D to 1D is given in my answer to this question: [Least Squares Minimization Complex Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745588/least-squares-minimization-complex-numbers/20104454#20104454)