# Least Squares Minimization Complex Numbers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I've been using my Matlab, but it's my vision to eventually switch over to doing all of my analysis in Python since it is an actual programming language and a few other reasons.

The recent problem I've been trying to tackle is to do least squares minimization of complex data. I'm an engineer and we deal with complex impedance pretty often, and I'm trying to use curve fitting to fit a simple circuit model to measured data.

The impedance equation is as follows:

Z(w) = 1/( 1/R + j*w*C ) + j*w*L

I'm then trying to find the values of R, C, and L such that the least squares curve is found.

I've tried using the optimization package such as optimize.curve_fit or optimize.leastsq, but they don't work with complex numbers.

I then tried making my residual function return the magnitude of the complex data, but this did not work either.

Comment: This seems exactly the same problem with a promising answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296790/python-scipy-leastsq-fit-with-complex-numbers

Answer (score 6):

Referring [to unutbu answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745792/62921), there is no need to reduce the available information by taking the magnitude squared in function residuals because `leastsq` does not care whether the numbers are real or complex, but only that they are are expressed as a 1D array, preserving the integrity of the functional relationship.

Here is a replacement residuals function:

```
def residuals(params, w, Z):
    R, C, L = params
    diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z
    z1d = np.zeros(Z.size*2, dtype = np.float64)
    z1d[0:z1d.size:2] = diff.real
    z1d[1:z1d.size:2] = diff.imag
    return z1d
```

This is the only change that need be made. The answers for the seed 2013 are: [2.96564781, 1.99929516, 4.00106534].

The errors relative to [to unutbu answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745792/62921) are reduced by significantly more than an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, the goal is to reduce the absolute value of sum of the squared
differences between the model and the observed `Z`:

```
abs(((model(w, *params) - Z)**2).sum())
```

My [original
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f800a38d-8b06-4507-9612-ee65cb59fdc2/view-source)
suggested applying `leastsq` to a `residuals` function which returns a scalar
representing the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary differences:

```
def residuals(params, w, Z):
    R, C, L = params
    diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z
    return diff.real**2 + diff.imag**2
```

[Mike Sulzer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104454/190597) using a
residual function which returns a vector of floats.

Here is a comparison of the result using these residual functions:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
j = 1j

def model1(w, R, C, L):
    Z = 1.0/(1.0/R + j*w*C) + j*w*L
    return Z

def model2(w, R, C, L):
    Z = 1.0/(1.0/R + j*w*C) + j*w*L
    # make Z non-contiguous and of a different complex dtype
    Z = np.repeat(Z, 2)
    Z = Z[::2]
    Z = Z.astype(np.complex64)
    return Z

def make_data(R, C, L):
    N = 10000
    w = np.linspace(0.1, 2, N)
    Z = model(w, R, C, L) + 0.1*(np.random.random(N) + j*np.random.random(N))
    return w, Z

def residuals(params, w, Z):
    R, C, L = params
    diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z
    return diff.real**2 + diff.imag**2

def MS_residuals(params, w, Z):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104454/190597 (Mike Sulzer)
    """
    R, C, L = params
    diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z
    z1d = np.zeros(Z.size*2, dtype=np.float64)
    z1d[0:z1d.size:2] = diff.real
    z1d[1:z1d.size:2] = diff.imag
    return z1d

def alt_residuals(params, w, Z):
    R, C, L = params
    diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z
    return diff.astype(np.complex128).view(np.float64)

def compare(*funcs):
    fmt = '{:15} | {:37} | {:17} | {:6}'
    header = fmt.format('name', 'params', 'sum(residuals**2)', 'ncalls')
    print('{}\n{}'.format(header, '-'*len(header)))
    fmt = '{:15} | {:37} | {:17.2f} | {:6}'
    for resfunc in funcs:
        # params, cov = optimize.leastsq(resfunc, p_guess, args=(w, Z))
        params, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = optimize.leastsq(
            resfunc, p_guess, args=(w, Z),
            full_output=True)
        ssr = abs(((model(w, *params) - Z)**2).sum())
        print(fmt.format(resfunc.__name__, params, ssr, infodict['nfev']))
    print(end='\n')

R, C, L = 3, 2, 4
p_guess = 1, 1, 1
seed = 2013

model = model1
np.random.seed(seed)
w, Z = make_data(R, C, L)
assert np.allclose(model1(w, R, C, L), model2(w, R, C, L))

print('Using model1')
compare(residuals, MS_residuals, alt_residuals)

model = model2
print('Using model2')
compare(residuals, MS_residuals, alt_residuals)
```

yields

```
Using model1
name            | params                                | sum(residuals**2) | ncalls
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
residuals       | [ 2.86950167  1.94245378  4.04362841] |              9.41 |     89
MS_residuals    | [ 2.85311972  1.94525477  4.04363883] |              9.26 |     29
alt_residuals   | [ 2.85311972  1.94525477  4.04363883] |              9.26 |     29

Using model2
name            | params                                | sum(residuals**2) | ncalls
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
residuals       | [ 2.86590332  1.9326829   4.0450271 ] |              7.81 |    483
MS_residuals    | [ 2.85422448  1.94853383  4.04333851] |              9.78 |    754
alt_residuals   | [ 2.85422448  1.94853383  4.04333851] |              9.78 |    754
```

So it appears which residual function to use may depend on the model function.  I'm
at a loss to explain the difference in result given the similarity of `model1` and
`model2`.

Comment: Complex number can be based on different width floats, based on the numpy documentation this view performs a byte level reinterpretation of the data, i.e. float could end up refereeing to np.float32 (theres also float16 and float64, while using np.complex128, this would be converted to 4 floats, and the actual values would be meaning less due to the structure of floating point numbers Mike Sulzer's answer is safe, as the value will be converted to the correct floating point size. You also could have non continuous memory, i.e. item size=16bytes, but strides = 20 bytes, its still a 1d array.

Comment: @glenflet: Thanks for the correction. The dtype mismatch problem can be fixed by
changing `diff.view('float')` to
`diff.astype(np.complex128).view(np.float64)`. (I've edited the answer above to
reflect this.) The non-contiguity problem does not occur because `diff` is the
difference of two arrays: `diff = model(w, R, C, L) - Z`. NumPy will always
create a contiguous array holding the result of `model(w, R, C, L) - Z` and
Python binds the variable name `diff` to it.

Comment: I'd say the difference you have between the two models is the size of floating point 'residuals' uses float32 for model2 as Z is np.complex64 i.e. 2 32 bit floats, the other two functions are casting to float64, you should compare number of function calls as well, from the doc's I believe step size defaults to 2*sqrt(machine precision), which is larger to float32, if you overrun maxfev (800 in your code) this is important. Also this could be skipping over a local mim, or their could be error in the sum of squares, though that shouldn't have such an impact.

Comment: @glenflet: I added the number of function calls to the output. One thing I don't understand is why `residuals` with `model2` finds parameters which are a **better fit for `model1`** than any of the residual functions paired with `model1` itself. As you pointed out, `model2` returns values with less resolution than `model1` so it does not make sense (to me) that the result should be better. Maybe it is dumb luck? Still, I wish I knew how to coax the same or better result out `leastsq` while using `model1`.

Comment: @glenflet interesting tidbit about the step size. what would you say is a good step size if you're using float32?

Comment: I run a detailed analysis of your code (I used least_squares, same thing but more functionality), the difference, regression is end by ftol for model 1 and xtol for model 2. The other factor is the residuals is not comparable to the other two, if you look closely at the function residuals is the square or the magnitude of the complex number where as the other 2 are sums over components, in effect residuals is squared twice hence it gives a larger ssr and encourages more aggressive regression (i.e. larger steps) if you correct this difference the results are more comparable.

Comment: Also while you made model 2 use 64bit complex, Z was still a 128 bit complex, hence when you subtract the 64bit complex value is extended to a 128 bit complex, by zero padding, it the results for model 2 are substantially dependent on whether Z is complex128 or complex64 at the point it is run. finally you should run the compassion several times with different seeds i.e. loop ever thing after setting the seed, the results don't always converge correctly and the better model varies, this is simply they are a different error test, i.e. magnitude vs components of the error.